# How to cast Core Data queryset to mutable Array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

There is a code containing description of Dictionary struct and receiving corresponding entries from Core Data

What string(s) should I insert before last bracket to cast NSArray to array of dictionaries?

```
struct Dictionary {
var name: String
var enableDirect: Bool
var enableReverse: Bool

init(name: String, enableDirect: Bool, enableReverse: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.enableDirect = enableDirect
    self.enableReverse = enableReverse
}
}

func loadDictionariesFromStore() -> [Dictionary] {
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Dictionaries")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

}
```

Comment: Why do you define your own dictionary since there is a builtin one? Or is it only your personal data structure?

Comment: It's language learning app. It's not a data structure. It can be en-ru dictionary or another

Comment: Which objects are in your `results` array? (Type, properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the `NSArray` is of type `[Dictionary]` you can make a forced downcast of `results` and return it:

```
return results as! [Dictionary]

// or directly return it
return context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as! [Dictionary]
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Type 'Dictionary' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'.

Comment: @VassiliyVorobyov What types do the elements in the array have? Try to look it up in the debugger.